# How to get started with ReflectInsight?

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, nlog, reflectinsight

I want to use Logging in a project which currently does not have any logging implementation. I was planning to use NLog but stumbled upon an answer here that said ReflectInsight is an even more powerful logging solution so I would like to give it a try. From what I have read so far I can conclude that I can use ReflectInsight native API or use its extensions with other Logging solutions such as Log4Net or NLog.

I want to use its native API but can't find a Getting started tutorial. Can anyone please tell me how can I implement ReflectInsight Api.

Kindly give me a very simple example which shows how can I save data to DB or some other XML or log file and then how can I view that logging info using its viewer?

A simple two lined method that throws an exception and then logs it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Afraz Ali, as promised here's the link to our samples. Sorry for the delay. http://reflectsoftware.com/Public/Support/Samples.aspx
 
Disclosure: I am one of the developers for the ReflectInsight .NET logging framework project

Answer (score 2):

ReflectSoftware has a [UserVoice](http://reflectsoftware.uservoice.com/) site and in it are a number of knowledge base articles which can help you get started. As [codematrix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2802981/codematrix) mentioned, we are working to get additional documentation out. Feel free to post suggestions or submit support requests through our [UserVoice](http://reflectsoftware.uservoice.com/) site.

Disclosure: I'm one of the developers on the ReflectInsight Team.

Comment: All docs have been moved from CodePlex to the following url: https://reflectsoftware.atlassian.net/wiki/display/RI5/ReflectInsight+5+documentation

Also the source code that was hosted on CodePlex is now on GitHub: https://github.com/reflectsoftware

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ReflectInsight's](http://insightextensions.codeplex.com/) codeplex project. It has some very good documentation.

```
void MyMethod() 
{ 
   using (RILogManager.Default.TraceMethod(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()))
   {
      try
      {
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          RILogManager.Default.SendException(e);
      }
   }    
}
```

They don't have a DB Listener but you can easily create your own. Start a [discussion](http://insightextensions.codeplex.com/discussions) on codeplex. They are very quick to respond will give you an example on how to start this off.

Comment: Thanks code5, I tired their codeplex site but all I can find is their Logging Extensions Getting Started documentation. Where is the documentation for their core API? Where did you get the above code from?